# How can I detect the background color of a webpage with PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS to rasterize some web pages with the render() function, and sometimes the resulting image has a black background (this is supposed to be a normal behaviour, as said at the bottom of the [FAQ](http://phantomjs.org/faq.html)).

But I'd like to set a white background ***only*** if the web page has not set its background color, like this :

```
page.evaluate(function() {
  if (getComputedStyle(document.body, null).backgroundColor === 'transparent') {
    document.body.bgColor = 'white';
  }
});
```

But it doesn't work at all. I also tried with :

```
=== 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
```

to no avail.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Have you tried debugging?  What is the background color equating to in your tests?  You may try:  if (!getComputedStyle(document.body, null).backgroundColor) { ... }    Which will work if backgroundColor is null, undefined, false, an empty string or any other 'falsy' value.

Comment: Computed style will never return null, undefined, false or an empty string for backgroundColor.

Comment: I inserted a console.log() message in the 'if' condition but it never shows. Btw, I checked with the Javascript console in Firefox and Chrome the value of 'getComputedStyle(document.body, null).backgroundColor' on a specific web page and it do returns 'transparent'...

Comment: @Silas If you want to notify some commentator of your comment, you should use [@replies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/266187).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem. Actually :

```
document.body.bgColor = 'white'
```

doesn't work. I've used instead :

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff'
```

and now I got the white background.

Comment: This doesn't really answer your original question of detecting background color.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that some pages can set background color on root `html` tag. Example is here:
http://helpdesk.symphonical.com/hc/en-us

Setting 'body' background color will override color from 'html' tag.

I ended up setting color for root `html` tag, this way even if `body` has other color it will hide our custom color from `html` in `page.evaluate`:

```
// test the top-level HTML tag since it can also contain backgroundColor
// and we don't wont to override it in body
if (getComputedStyle(document.documentElement, null).backgroundColor === 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)') {
    console.log('document.documentElement backgroundColor is transparent, setting color to white');
    var style = document.createElement('style'),
    text = document.createTextNode('body { background: #fff }');
    style.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    style.appendChild(text);
    document.documentElement.insertBefore(style, document.documentElement.firstChild);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just append a style element with the lowest useful specificity (1) for body as the first element of head. The engine would automatically use the background which came later. In case none came later, this one would be used.

```
page.evaluate(function(){
    var s = document.createElement('style');
    s.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    s.innerText = "body { background-color: white; }";

    // assuming head exists and is not empty:
    document.head.insertBefore(s, document.head.firstChild);
});
```

You could also try `* { background-color: white; }` with a specificity of 0.

Comment: I tried your solution but the background remains black. Yet, the page.evaluate() function works well since it can return the correct page title. I don't know what I'm doing wrong... (btw, my test page is unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I see that the background-color is explicitly set as `transparent`, so this approach won't work. This only work if the background-color is never set.

Comment: So that brings us to the initial question : how can I detect if the background color is set to a specific value ?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem on unix.SE, because in v1.9.7 on windows/linux the default background-color is white and I could just compare it successfully with `=== 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'`. I really don't see a problem. What version are you using?